# How to delete an object from Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to delete a file from my S3 bucket using `aws-sdk` but no luck so far... AWS S3 `delete_object` method returns `DeleteObjectOutput` structure with **all** `nil` attributes:

```
#<struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=nil, version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>
```

But later when I check a folder directory in my bucket I can see that a file is still there.

Code is below.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

**config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb**

```
Aws.config.update({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(
      ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], 
      ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})
```

**my_controller.rb**

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
response = s3.delete_object({
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    key: params[:attachment_url]
})
# response == <struct Aws::S3::Types::DeleteObjectOutput delete_marker=nil, version_id=nil, request_charged=nil>
```

Comment: Your URL is probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my key was not directly pointing to a file, but to a folders which contain that file. As you can see I have slashes in filename to distinguish folders.

```
key = 'one/two/three/file.png'
```

But for some unknown to me reason these slashes (upon file uploading to S3) were replaced by S3 with `%2F` characters.

For file deletion to successfully work I needed to convert %2F back to '/' before passing a key to `delete_object` method. Cheers :)

=======

But it still not nice from Amazon to not return any message about either deletion was succesfull or not...

Comment: You didn't get an error because `DELETE` on S3 is an idempotent operation -- it always succeeds if the request is authorized.  Follow the logic: after a successful delete operation, the file doesn't exist... right?  Now... if it didn't exist before you tried to delete it, that's technically still true after -- after you delete a non-existent object, it then (still) doesn't exist.  Hence, technically, your request "succeeded," because now it really, really doesn't exist, exactly as would have been the case if it had existed before you deleted it.